# How to extract specific characters in R String

Tags: r

I have a file name string:

```
directoryLocation<-"\Users\me\Dropbox\Work\"
```

How can I extract all the "\" and replace it with "\"? In other languages, you can loop through the string and then replace character by character, but I don't think you can do that in R.

I tried

```
substr(directoryLocation,1,1)
```

but it is highly optimized to this case...how can it be more general?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to replace "\" with "/"?

Comment: Your example string gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` is the general tool for this, but as others have noted you need a confusing four slashes to account for the escapes: you need to escape for both R text and the regexp engine simultaneously.

An alternative, if using Windows, is to use `normalizePath` and setting the `winslash` parameter:

```
normalizePath(directoryLocation,winslash="/",mustWork=FALSE)
[1] "C:/Users/me/Dropbox/Work/"
```

Though this may perform additional work on expanding relative paths to absolute ones (seen here by prepending with `C:`).

Answer (score 0):

In theory this would do what you want

```
 gsub("\\\", "/", directoryLocation)
```

however...

```
R> directoryLocation<-"\\Users\\me\\Dropbox\\Work\\"
R> directoryLocation
[1] "\\Users\\me\\Dropbox\\Work\\"
R> gsub("\\\\", "/", directoryLocation)
[1] "/Users/me/Dropbox/Work/"
```

Comment: I don't see why your 'in theory' suggestion would be what one would want to do.  And since it doesn't work and you don't comment on it other than saying that you apparently think it should work in theory I don't see why you included that part in your answer.

Comment: when i tried it, the problem is that "/" is an escape character therefore it makes the input into console to wait for more input.

Comment: The in theory part was if the OP's example worked. OP's example gives a syntax error...

Answer (score 0):

At least on windows one needs to escape all of the backslashes, but `gsub` is what you want.

```
gsub("\\\\","/","\\Users\\me\\Dropbox\\Work\\")
[1] "/Users/me/Dropbox/Work/"
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows …

Comment: Has everything to do with windows.  The need to escape `\` is universal but the path is very likely to have come from a windows machine.